# Aplicar plugin Select2 con vue.js

Tags: select2, vue.js

Estoy tratando de aplicar el plugin `Select2` sobre un `select` que lo cargo utilizando **VUE.JS** (hago un `v-for` sobre el option del `select`)

Si **no** aplico el plugin, al hacer `v-model="modelo"`, puedo utilizar la variable `({{modelo}})` de forma correcta.

Pero si aplico el plugin, **VUE** deja de leer el `v-model` y no puedo utilizar el `databinding`.

Adjunto el JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/rLmztr2d/11/

Código:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#divMain",
  data: {
    selected: 'A',
    options: [
      { text: 'One', value: 'A' },
      { text: 'Two', value: 'B' },
      { text: 'Three', value: 'C' }
    ]
  }
});

$('#miSelect').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select an option'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
<div id="divMain">

  <select id="miSelect" v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="opt in options" v-bind:value="opt.value">
      {{ opt.text }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quizá es un poco "tricky" pero aquí te dejo tu fiddle modificado y funcionando:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    selected: 'A',
    options: [
      { text: 'One', id: 'A' },
      { text: 'Two', id: 'B' },
      { text: 'Three', id: 'C' }
    ]
  },
  mounted() {
   let self = this; // ámbito de vue
    
    // inicializas select2
    $('#miSelect')
      .select2({ 
       placeholder: 'Select an option',
       data: self.options, // cargas los datos en vez de usar el loop
       })
       // nos hookeamos en el evento tal y como puedes leer en su documentación
       .on('select2:select', function () {       
        var value = $("#miSelect").select2('data');
        // nos devuelve un array
        
        // ahora simplemente asignamos el valor a tu variable selected de VUE
        self.selected = value[0].id
      })
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">

  <select id="miSelect"></select>
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>

</div>
```